# Java "mystic" menu name

Tags: java, menu

I want to know more about the menu above, but I can't find a name for it.

This picture is taken from Spotify, and I guess everybody knows what it does: Stores all "Tracks" under Track, All Artists under Artist etc. Also when you click on e.g Track, it will sort them from a-z (same menu are used in Windows, inside folders).

I'm not even sure this is a Java feature, but I'll have to ask anyway!

[image: Spotify screenshot showing menu in question]

Comment: I have no freaking idea what spotify is, but I can tell you what your looking for is probably known as "table header".

Comment: @Durandal I just edited in the screenshot correctly, does that help you?

Comment: I didn't understand your question. The sorting of the objects can be done through sorting algorithms, some of them already implemented in Java.

Comment: @BrunoToffolo The question isn't to determine hwo to sort it, but how such a UI element is displayed with such subheadings.

Comment: @hexafraction I can't see any difference, I guess your edit and my comment overlapped somewhat. And I lied a little, I know spotify is some music related service, but I always find it strange that some people assume "one has to know this <newest fad on the internet>". And it still looks like a table header, and I'm sure thats what it is :)

Comment: @Durandal I can only tell you one thing.. Look up Spotify :-)! and ya, a "table header" is what i was looking for, thank you!